# iOS Static library compilation error - table of contents is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a Objective C static library for iOS. When I try to compile it gives following warnings.

```
Libtool /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-eyucoczochpovhcqduwoieknpyer/Build/Intermediates/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMyLib.a normal armv7
cd /Users/******/Desktop/MyLib
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-eyucoczochpovhcqduwoieknpyer/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-eyucoczochpovhcqduwoieknpyer/Build/Intermediates/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyLib.LinkFileList -ObjC -framework Foundation -o /Users/shafraz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-eyucoczochpovhcqduwoieknpyer/Build/Intermediates/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMyLib.a
```

I am getting similar errors for armv7s, arm64 also

```
(null): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: warning for library: /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-eyucoczochpovhcqduwoieknpyer/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMyLib.a for architecture: armv7 the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

I am getting similar errors for armv7s, arm64 also

This worming shown only after removing MyLib.m and class declaration in MyLib.h file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to remove the derived data folder and clean your project.

Comment: Now some are gone but still getting following warnings  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: warning for library: /Users/shafraz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-eyucoczochpovhcqduwoieknpyer/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMyLib.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)

Comment: Any solutions? I see this for a newly Xcode created static library project.

Comment: @RawCCode Still couldn't find any solution

Comment: I am having the same problem too. I am using Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: quellish's answer seems to be correct. If you don't have a class in the library, only categories, you'll see the error. The fix is simple: add a class

Comment: I am using this hack to hide this warning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31685208/5166489

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This generally happens if your static library contains nothing but categories or informal protocols. The linker is warning you that you don't seem to have any classes to link.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I realized that the library I wrote ended up being a header only library. That implies I don't even need to compile a library, just include the headers in "Header Search Paths" in "Build settings".