# Silence "table of contents is empty" warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Is it possible to silence the "table of contents is empty" warning when linking a library that contains only categories?

> warning:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   warning for library: {some library} for architecture: {some
>   architecture} the table of contents is empty (no object file members
>   in the library define global symbols)

I'm aware that adding an empty class in any implementation file would remove the warning, but I would prefer not to add an artificial class.

Comment: My vague understanding of the libtool.c source code (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-698/misc/libtool.c) tells me it's not possible. Maybe silencing all libtool warnings?

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute libtool with your own wrapper:

- rename libtool to to libtool.orig
- create executable libtool script with following content:

  ```
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr /bin/libtool.orig $* 2>&1 | grep -v "the table of contents is empty"
     exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
  ```

Xcode will not show this annoying message anymore.

Answer (score 1):

libtool accepts -no_warning_for_no_symbols option.